# Need to be refreshed only div not the whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an div and inside that div I have a link as

```
<a href="#" onclick="Edit_popup();" >edit</a>
```

When I click on this link the whole page is getting refreshed. But I need only this div to be refreshed not whole page. I am calling this as :

```
function Edit_popup(){
var criteria=prompt("Please enter id");
if (id=="Login" || id=="login")
   {
   $("#criteria").load("page2.html");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with

```
    <a href="#" onclick="Edit_popup(); return false;" >edit</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the whole page is getting refreshed is because you have clicked on a link and the link's default behavior is to send you to it's `href`.  (If you look at your browser's  address line, you'll notice the URL ends in `/#`.)

The correct way to prevent this is to pass the event to the function

```
onclick="Edit_popup(e);"
```

and then stop the event's (in this case, the click's) default behavior:

```
function Edit_popup (e) {
    var criteria=prompt("Please enter id");

    e.preventDefault(); // this line cancels the link

    if (id=="Login" || id=="login") {
        $("#criteria").load("page2.html");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `e.preventDefault();` inside your function so that you can do whatever you want then use `e.preventDefault();` that 'll prevent the browser from performing the default action for that link.

kindly check this link to understand the difference between `return false;` and `e.preventDefault();` [return-false-and-prevent-default](http://css-tricks.com/return-false-and-prevent-default/)